# CSS Filter from white to custom color, properties

Tags: html, css, swift, filter, wkwebview

I have different HTML templates and i'm trying to get the "dark mode" from them.
I achieve this by injecting some css into them.

```
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
   html {
       filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(.5turn);
   }

   img {
       filter: invert(1) hue-rotate(.5turn);
   }
}
```

With this my html is perfectly converted from white to dark. And I'm quiete happy with this.
The problem is that my custom color for dark mode is not a pure black.

So I'm trying to convert my light html to my custom dark mode that has this background color: **#333C4C**.

I've tried different calculators to convert from an #FFFFFF to my custom color, and I get for example:

```
-webkit-filter: brightness(50%) sepia(1) hue-rotate(179.4deg) saturate(101.4%) brightness(101.4%);
filter: brightness(50%) sepia(1) hue-rotate(179.4deg) saturate(101.4%) brightness(101.4%)
```

The problem is that my whole template is blurred with some light blue while with my inital code only the white background and text was changed.

How can I convert my light mode html to my custom dark mode? I thought the initial code was perfect, I only need to make it **#333C4C** instead of black.

---

Update with images:

[image: Image with my code]

[image: Image with your code]

[image: What I am trying to achieve]

Comment: did you try this one ? https://codepen.io/brucebentley/pen/orGPRg

Comment: @MaxiGui thanks for the answers! But I dont have an svg, I have a whole html template

Answer (score 2):

Filter wont be able to to convert from white to a dark color. for Dark color, you should start from black.

As you said, if you start from [white](https://codepen.io/jumarjuaton/full/mdJYWYq), it would give you `filter: invert(19%) sepia(28%) saturate(590%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(89%) contrast(84%);` which would be equal to `#9AB8D3`.

But if you start from [black](https://codepen.io/sosuke/pen/Pjoqqp), it will give you the perfect result: `filter: invert(20%) sepia(13%) saturate(1155%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(93%) contrast(87%);` which is equal to `#333C4C`

Demo:

```css
#I1, #I2{
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
}
#I1 {
  background: #fff;
  filter: invert(19%) sepia(28%) saturate(590%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(89%) contrast(84%);
}
#I2{
  background: #000;
  filter: invert(20%) sepia(13%) saturate(1155%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(93%) contrast(87%);
}
```

```html
<div id="I1"></div>
<div id="I2"></div>
```

### Demo complex:

```css
body{
  margin:0;
  background-color: #333C4C;
  padding: 20px;
}
body > * :not(img){
  color:white;
  background: #000;
  filter: invert(20%) sepia(13%) saturate(1155%) hue-rotate(180deg) brightness(93%) contrast(87%);
}
```

```html
<div id="I2">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla tempus tempus leo, eget fermentum ante aliquet hendrerit. Curabitur auctor in libero eget fringilla. Phasellus eleifend eu sem feugiat feugiat. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec commodo libero ante, at maximus sem tincidunt ac. Fusce at ullamcorper purus. Nam lobortis, justo vel aliquam rutrum, augue nulla consectetur tellus, non eleifend ex orci id tortor. Donec at porta mauris. Vestibulum in magna ultrices, sodales nulla at, ultrices lacus. Pellentesque nec ante ac sem varius venenatis. Nam sit amet neque libero. Quisque ante augue, vestibulum id ex non, malesuada accumsan nisi. Quisque id aliquet urna, vitae volutpat tellus. Pellentesque nec neque at tortor facilisis auctor. Donec aliquet faucibus enim quis viverra. Nulla scelerisque vestibulum augue quis posuere.</p>
  <img src="https://dummyimage.com/400x400/fff/000">
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you again for the answers! But with this approach the whole view is covered with this light blue and the images are ruined. I would like to change only the background the text accordingly and let the images as they are. With my first sample code I can change the background and text (but wiht a black) but I noticed that my images are changed to. 

How can I change background and text only? The text is perfectly correct with my first sample code

Comment: I dont have your html, so I cannot help much more with an example.

Comment: I retrieve different html from network. I dont have a fixed html or file. I have for example an email from apple and I can see from Gmail that with dark mode it is custom black and with light mode it is white. Withouth ruining images.

Comment: I cant help you further without code or image example of your problem

Comment: @MaxGui I added three images of the problem. The first one is my code. The second one is your code, and the third image is what I am trying to achieve

Comment: ok so you are adding this background on the body ? If so, you can probably go around with negative margin on horizontale and add a padding to compensate that on your images. You would be able set that for every image. I am going to try to show you my answer

Comment: Uhm, remember that this is only an example. I'm trying to find an "universal" way for every template I have. I could have a Google html with different stuff. But the same purpose: convert white background to my custom dark color without ruining it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231921/discussion-between-maxigui-and-manubrio).